# Jenkins fails to build maven project (Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0)

Tags: hudson, jenkins, maven-3

1) I created new job of type "Build a maven2/3 project".

Build on Jenkins fails requiring tools:jar:1.5.0, but this project uses Java SE 6 (that is java 1.6)

```
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 at specified path D:\Jenkins\jre/../lib/tools.jar
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:260)
    ... 34 more
```

I am using latest versions: jenkins 1.421, maven 3.0.3

update:
Maven pom says to use 1.6. There's no trace of intention to use 1.5

```
        <plugin> <!-- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

2) Finally I tried to create new job of type "Build a free-style software project".
It works, no this error. Up to the maven package phase.
This however requires more configuration, that I right now don't know.
And **I can't get packaged result on jenkins page**.

update: Solved! Needed to add JDK (the same as JAVA_HOME) in Jenkins configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You trying to run the build under a 1.5 JRE instead of JDK which is required by Maven to run. You need a 1.5 JDK and not only a JRE!

Comment: How to force maven to use JDK not JRE?

Comment: Have you set JAVA_HOME or have you set in your Jenkins configuration to use JDK ? Have you setup Jekins with correct JDK versions? You can configure a Job in Jekins to use a particular Java version if correctly setup jenkins.

Comment: Default "Build a maven2/3 project" doesn't propose to set JDK
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22

Comment: Is the message caused by a dependency which is defined in a POM file? Can you post the pom of the project which causes the problem?